# Silverlight client does not recognize namespace defined in ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, namespaces

**Silverlight client does not recognize namespace defined in ASP.NET project**

I have observed the following error when providing a using statement for a namespace that is defined in my ASP.NET project:

*"The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'FitnessTrackerPlus'"*

**I observed that I cannot simply add the .Web reference to my silverlight client.**

Thanks in advance,

Scott Nimrod

Answer (score 0):

So you said you observed this but I don't see any question. What is your question? Do you WANT to include that namespace in your Silverlight project? Silverlight won't be able to simply reference items in an ASP.Net project as they're different projects and there is a separation between where Silverlight and where ASP.Net run.

You'll probably want to create a class library and reference it in both places...if that was your question.

Comment: My question is how do I resolve the error regarding an invalid namespace. I am working out of a tutorial book by Wrox. In their solution they only have two projects. One is the silverlight client and the other is the ASP.NET Web project. As a result, I believe that their solution did not require creating a third project.